# Error using space in html postamble when exporting org file

Tags: org-export, html

I am using html export feature for org files and I want to change the value of html-postamble (see [doc](https://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-preamble-and-postamble.html)).

Here is the `index.org` file:

```
#+title: Home

Welcome

#+options: html-postamble:"TESTSPACE"
```

When I export with `M-x org-html-export-as-html` everything is all right and I have the following at the end of the html produced buffer:

```html
<div id="postamble" class="status">
TESTSPACE
</div>
```

But if I add a space:

```
#+title: Home

Welcome

#+options: html-postamble:"TEST SPACE"
```

it raises this error I cannot solve:
`org-export--parse-option-keyword: End of file during parsing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a bug, which you should report to the Org mode mailing list with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.

You can work around it though, by doing something like this:

```org
#+TITLE: Home

#+OPTIONS: html-postamble:t
#+BIND: org-html-postamble-format (("en" "Test Case"))

Welcome
```

That uses the [BIND](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Export-Settings) mechanism to assign a value to `org-html-postamble-format` for this file only and only during export. The value is an alist with elements of the form `(lang format)` where both `lang` and `format` are strings. The `format` string can have values interpolated using a `%` format mechanism. Do `C-h v org-html-postamble-format` for details.

The BIND mechanism is not enabled by default though, so you will need to add the following to your init file:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'ox
   (setq org-export-allow-bind-keywords t))
```

Comment: Bug reported! Nice workaraound, I will try to make it work. My final goal is to use an elisp function to construct the postamble string. This function needs to be aware of some settings of the current file, do you even think this is possible?

Comment: Yes, it should be quite possible, but depending on what exactly you want to do, it might be possible to use `org-html-postamble-format` which allows you to use some settings from the current file. See its doc string: `C-h v org-html-postamble-format`